# Carrier Wave gem and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I read here that Heroku doesn't allow you to store photos on their server and that people use CarrierWave gem with Amazon to store photos. However, I just watched Ryan Bate's Carrier Wave RailsCasts and he also mentions how CarrierWave has a remote url option whereby it will, in his words, "download" the photo from a URL and display it on your site.   Does this mean that it stays on the remote server and just gets presented by CarrierWave on the Heroku site? I assume Carrier Wave's not somehow attempting to transfer the image at the url to the new server?

Might be a stupid question but I don't know a lot about servers (or anything :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the remote url option for CarrierWave gives the user a different way of providing the picture to your server: instead of uploading the picture file directly, the user may give a URL where the picture is (say, on a Flickr account, or something).  When this is provided to the application using CarrierWave, the picture is downloaded from the third-party location (given by the url) to the application server -- just as if the user had uploaded it directly -- and then stored to Amazon's S3.

Comment: Long story short, you'll still need an amazon S3 or similar account for storage. Carrier wave supports Amazon S3 storage using Fog. See the Amazon S3 section for details https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I was wondering whether the remote url option might allow me to present the photo without using Amazon. I've never used amazon before...

Comment: @Michael No, CarrierWave's `remote_url` method downloads the image file to the Heroku server, processes it (if necessary) in a tmp directory, and then stores it in whichever storage provider you are using.  If you just want to display a remote image, do so with an `image_tag` helper